# Java BigDecimal valueOf not precise?

Tags: java

I am not sure if I am using this wrong but, if I do `BigDecimal.valueOf(15350.00)`, why does it show as `15350.0` instead of `15350.00`?

Comment: The two are not identical at all. I thought BigDecimal should recognize precision and scale when using valueOf. When doing an assert statement, the two are not identical so how can you say they are identical?

Comment: They aren't identical. BigDecimal values express a value with an associated precision. The number of trailing digits in the string representation indicates that precision, even if those digits are all zero.

Comment: why it shows `15350.0`: documentation of [`valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html#valueOf(double)) *"Translates a double into a BigDecimal, using the double's canonical string representation provided by the Double.toString(double) method."* and `toString(15350.00)` will return `"15350.0"` and not `"15350.00"` ||| internally (or compiled) the doubles `15350d`, `15350.0`, `15350.00`, `15350.000`, ... are all the same, `valueOf` cannot know which was used in source code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although `15350.00` and `15350.0` are two different BigDecimal values, `BigDecimal.valueOf(15350.00)` is constructing the BigDecimal using a Double. The double literals `15350.00` and `15350.0` both correspond to the same exact integer value, without the precision semantics of BigDecimal.

Answer (score 9):

When working with `BigDecimal`, prefer using the `BigDecimal(String)` constructor over `valueOf(double)`. `new BigDecimal("15350.00")` will preserve your trailing zeroes.